# split files into fixed-size blocks in C

Tags: c, file, split, partitioning

I am asked to split files into fixed-size blocks to do the file encryption. More specifically, I have lots of files, which could be binary or text.

I am asked to write a user program that takes as input these files, splits each file into say many 32-bit blocks, and then sends out the 32-bit blocks.

The scenario is that the user backups their files in a remote server by splitting their files into blocks, encrypting the blocks (using RSA), and then sending the ciphertexts to the server.

Consider two files, one is a 33-bit text file A and another is a 34-bit binary file B.
A can be partitioned into two 32-bit blocks A1 and A2 (the last 31 bis of A2 are all 0's).
B can be partitioned into two 32-bit blocks B1 and B2 (the last 30 bis of B2 are all 0's).
If I obtain A1 (or A2, B1, B2), then I regard A1 as a 32-bit integer and can do the RSA encryption.

I am able to write code for RSA encryption, but unfortunately I have no idea about how to write the C code for obtaining A1, A2, B1, B2.

Can anyone help me write a sample code or give me some reference?

Comment: I always found these tutorials useful: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: I don't know any computer system where you can have a "33-bit text file". Files contain whole bytes, not bits.

Comment: You want to do it in C or C++?

Comment: I read http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ before, but still have no idea how to do. For example, the webpage says that we need different codes for text and binary files. So, a standard procedure is to first know whether the file under consideration is binary or text, and then use different pieces of codes to handle them?

Comment: is it inappropriate to do this in C/C++?

Comment: @user4478: It's appropriate. But C/C++ is not a language: you have to choose whether you want to do it in C, or you want to do it in C++. They are very different languages. Pick one.

Comment: I am more familiar with C. I pick C.

Comment: When doing encryption, it is safe to treat text files as binary files.

Comment: In real RSA you are working with 700 to 4000 bit keys.  You would want to encrypt in blocks that are the biggest multiple of bytes smaller than your key.  For example, with a 700 bit key you would encrypt 87 byte blocks because 87 * 8 = 696 bits.

Comment: So, brian you mean I don't need to distinguish whether I am reading text or binary. What I need to do is to treat every file as a binary file, right?

Comment: When you tell the runtime libraries a file is text, they change how they handle end-of-line characters.  For encrypting you don't care about that.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the high-level algorithm which you can easily convert to C code:

```
char* get_Next_Block_From_File(FILE *fp, int seek_offset, int blockSize)
{
    // Open file
    // lseek to seek_offset

    len = blockSize / 8;
    bit_pos = blockSize % 8;

    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        copy_from_file_to_local_buffer_byte_by_byte();
    }

    if (bit_pos) {
        byte[i] <<= (8 - bit_pos);
        append_byte_to_local_buffer();
    }

    return local_buffer;
}
```

Comment: but what I want is to know which function i should call

Answer (score 0):

```
C Program for splitting the given file into fixed size blocks

// split.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define SEGMENT 600 //approximate target size of small file

long file_size(char *name);//function definition below
int splitFile(char *fp1, size_t maxSize);


long file_size(char *name)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(name, "rb"); //must be binary read to get bytes

    long size=-1;
    if(fp)
    {
        fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(fp)+1;
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return size;
}

/*
**  splitFile
**  Splits an existing input file into multiple output files with a specified
**  maximum file size.
**
**  Return Value:
**  Number of created result files, or 0 in case of bad input data or a negative
**  value in case of an error during file splitting.
*/
int splitFile()
{
    int result = 0;

    char buffer[1024];//change see //2098 * 16
    size_t size;
    size_t read;
    size_t written;

    int segments=0, i, len, accum;

    //FILE *fp1, *fp2;

    char filename[260]={""};
    //char filename[260]={"D:\\smallFileName_"};//base name for small files.
    char largeFileName[]={"D:\\Payload_data\\Datafile_to_split.txt"};//change to your path
    long sizeFile = file_size(largeFileName);
    char smallFileName[260];
    char line[1024];
    long maxSize= sizeFile/SEGMENT + 1;
    int filecounter=1;

    FILE *fIn;
    FILE *fOut;
    fIn = fopen(largeFileName, "rb");

    if ((fIn != NULL) && (maxSize > 0))
    {
       // fIn = fopen(fIn, "rb");
        if (fIn != NULL)
        {
            fOut = NULL;
            result = 1;   /* we have at least one part */

            // Splitting Data from pchar into multiple files
                for(i=1; i<25 ;i++)
                    {               
                        sprintf(smallFileName, "%s%d.txt", filename, i);                      
                         printf("\n File number %d",i);
                         while (!feof(fIn))
                         {
                         /* initialize (next) output file if no output file opened */
                              if (fOut == NULL)
                              {  
                                 filecounter++;

                                sprintf(buffer, "smallFileName_%d", filecounter);
                                fOut = fopen(buffer, "wb");
                             if (fOut == NULL)
                             { 
                                 result *= -1;   
                                 break; 
                             }

                                size = 0;
                             }

                /* calculate size of data to be read from input file in order to not exceed maxSize */
                read = sizeof(buffer);
                if ((size + read) > maxSize)
                {
                    read = maxSize - size;
                }

                /* read data from input file */
                read = fread(buffer, 1, read, fIn);
                if (read == 0)
                {
                    result *= -1;
                    break;
                }

                /* write data to output file */
                written = fwrite(buffer, 1, read, fOut);

                if (written != read)
                {
                    result *= -1;
                    break;
                }

                /* update size counter of current output file */
                size += written;
                if (size >= maxSize)   /* next split? */
                {
                    fclose(fOut);
                    fOut = NULL;
                    result++;
                }
            }

            /* clean up */
            if (fOut != NULL)
            {
                fclose(fOut);
            }
            fclose(fIn);
        }
    } 
}
    return (result);
}


int main(void)
{


    //segments = sizeFile/SEGMENT + 1;//ensure end of file


    //fp1 = fopen(largeFileName, "r");

    ////if(fp1)
    ////{
    //    for(i=0;i<segments;i++)
    //    {
    //        accum = 0;
    //        sprintf(smallFileName, "%s%d.txt", filename, i);
    //        fp2 = fopen(smallFileName, "w");
    //        if(fp2)
    //        {
    //            while(fgets(line, 1080, fp1) && accum <= SEGMENT)
    //            {
    //                accum += strlen(line);//track size of growing file
    //                fputs(line, fp2);
    //            }
    //            fclose(fp2);
    //        }
    //    }
    //    fclose(fp1);
    //}


    //maxSize =sizeFile/SEGMENT + 1;
    //ensure end of file
    splitFile();

    getch();
    printf("\n File splitted Successfully");
    return 0;
}
```